# Possible flex layout bugs in IE and Chrome?

Tags: css, flexbox

This is a basic, "what's wrong in this code" question. I've written up some flex and based on my understanding it should work.

Here's the scenario:
 - On the right hand of `.card` there are a set of `.clickBoxes`. These will always be a fixed count and a fixed height so I can calculate the flex-basis `.top` based on that height.
 - `.bottom` should always line up with the very bottom of the `.clickBoxes`

What I assume should happen is that the flex: 1 0 100px of .top should allow it to grow based on it's content but not shrink below the 100px.

Given this assumption, Firefox is the only browser to perform this correctly. [image: Comparison of IE, Firefox and Chrome]

I'm aware I can move to a table type of layout (and probably will just to work around this) but I'm more just curious if there is something with my interpretation of how flex is supposed to work.

```css
        .card {
            background-color: green;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            flex-wrap: nowrap;
            margin: 20px 0px;
        }
        
        .card>.content {
            flex: 1 1 auto;
            background-color: blue;
            width: 300px;
            color: white;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            flex-wrap: nowrap;
        }
        
        .card>.content>* {
            flex: 0 0 auto;
        }
        
        .card>.content>.top {
            flex: 1 0 100px;
            background-color: blue;
            color: white;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            flex-wrap: nowrap;
            justify-content: space-between;
            padding: 10px;
        }
        
        .card>.content>.top>* {
            flex: 0 0 auto;
        }
        
        .card>.content>.bottom {
            flex: 1 1 auto;
            background-color: green;
            color: white;
        }
        
        .card>.clickBoxes {
            flex: 0 0 20px;
            background-color: red;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            flex-wrap: nowrap;
        }
        
        .card>.clickBoxes>* {
            background-color: yellow;
            flex: 0 0 18px;
            margin: 1px;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="card">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="top">
                <div>There should be 10 lines</div>
                <div>1</div>
                <div>2</div>
                <div>3</div>
                <div>4</div>
                <div>5</div>
                <div>6</div>
                <div>7</div>
                <div>8</div>
                <div>9</div>
                <div>10</div>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom">
                And this should be under everything
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clickBoxes">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="top">
                <div>This should be at the top</div>
                <div>This should be at the bottom</div>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom">
                And this should be under everything
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clickBoxes">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Looks like the MDN documentation says:
The flex-basis CSS property specifies the flex basis which is the initial main size of a flex item. This property determines the size of the content-box unless specified otherwise using box-sizing.
So given that it's the initial size and that I've defined flex-grow, it should resize to be larger given the content overflows.

The more I look into this the more it seems like a css bug in everything but Firefox.

Comment: I've contacted the IE team... anyone know anyone from Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a flex container to adapt to it's inner content size, specify auto for the flex-basis.

Flex-grow: 1; will make it grow if there is available height in the container (so it works the other way, looking up in the hierarchy and not down)

```css
        .card {
            background-color: green;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            flex-wrap: nowrap;
            margin: 20px 0px;
        }
        
        .card>.content {
            flex: 1 1 auto;
            background-color: blue;
            width: 300px;
            color: white;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            flex-wrap: nowrap;
        }
        
        .card>.content>* {
            flex: 0 0 auto;
        }
        
        .card>.content>.top {
            flex: 1 0 auto; /* changed */
            background-color: blue;
            color: white;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            flex-wrap: nowrap;
            justify-content: space-between;
            padding: 10px;
        }
        
        .card>.content>.top>* {
            flex: 0 0 auto;
        }
        
        .card>.content>.bottom {
            flex: 1 1 auto;
            background-color: green;
            color: white;
        }
        
        .card>.clickBoxes {
            flex: 0 0 20px;
            background-color: red;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            flex-wrap: nowrap;
        }
        
        .card>.clickBoxes>* {
            background-color: yellow;
            flex: 0 0 18px;
            margin: 1px;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="card">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="top">
                <div>There should be 10 lines</div>
                <div>1</div>
                <div>2</div>
                <div>3</div>
                <div>4</div>
                <div>5</div>
                <div>6</div>
                <div>7</div>
                <div>8</div>
                <div>9</div>
                <div>10</div>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom">
                And this should be under everything
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clickBoxes">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="top">
                <div>This should be at the top</div>
                <div>This should be at the bottom</div>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom">
                And this should be under everything
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clickBoxes">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: But it works fine in Firefox. Also, in Chrome, if you switch the `flex-basis: 100px` component to `auto`, then it works. But when you switch back to `100px`, it remains at the extended size. Your explanation makes sense, but I think there might be more to this.

Comment: So actually it doesn't work if you set it to auto. The green div comes up to high... It's top should be aligned with the clickboxes bottom. I agree that it all renders similarly across all browsers but for this specific scenario for alignment purposes, it doesn't work.

Comment: You mean in the second case ?  It is working ok for me. *card* set it's size to the maximum size of it's contents, in this case clickboxes. Now, content adapts it's size to card. Now, top and bottom grow to adapt to content. For me, it's ok...  (And in this case, flex-grow works because *content* has more height . than the sum of top and bottom)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another attempt at an answer which only breaks in chrome. Again based on my understanding of flex, it should theoretically work but doesn't.

In .card>.content>.top, mix @Michael-b's answer of using `flex: 1 1 auto` and adding `min-height:100px;`

Grrr bad Chrome! Bad!

[image: Comparison of attached code between chrome IE and Firefox]

```css
        .card {
            background-color: green;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            flex-wrap: nowrap;
            margin: 20px 0px;
        }
        
        .card>.content {
            flex: 1 1 auto;
            background-color: blue;
            color: white;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            flex-wrap: nowrap;
        }
        
        .card>.content>* {
            flex: 0 0 auto;
        }
        
        .card>.content>.top {
            flex: 1 0 auto;
            min-height: 100px;
            background-color: blue;
            color: white;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            flex-wrap: nowrap;
            justify-content: space-between;
            padding: 10px;
        }
        
        .card>.content>.top>* {
            flex: 0 0 auto;
        }
        
        .card>.content>.bottom {
            flex: 1 1 auto;
            background-color: green;
            color: white;
        }
        
        .card>.clickBoxes {
            flex: 0 0 20px;
            background-color: red;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            flex-wrap: nowrap;
        }
        
        .card>.clickBoxes>* {
            background-color: yellow;
            flex: 0 0 18px;
            margin: 1px;
        }
```

```html
<div class="card">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="top">
                <div>There should be 10 lines</div>
                <div>1</div>
                <div>2</div>
                <div>3</div>
                <div>4</div>
                <div>5</div>
                <div>6</div>
                <div>7</div>
                <div>8</div>
                <div>9</div>
                <div>10</div>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom">
                And this should be under everything
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clickBoxes">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="top">
                <div>This should be at the top</div>
                <div>This should be at the bottom</div>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom">
                And this should be under everything
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clickBoxes">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```